# ajaxtoolkit:numericupdownextender increment button does not work on button click

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying a simple asp.net web page with the ajaxtoolkit:numericupdownextender, I have linked it to a text box. It works when I click the down button, but it does not accept  any click on the up increment button. I cannot understand why ?

I am trying this in VS 2017, .Net Version is 4.7, And AjaxToolKit Version is 18.1.1.0.

Its a basic code from my web page.

```
<%@ Page Title="About" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" 
AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="About.aspx.vb" 
Inherits="WebApplication1.About" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" 
runat="server">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxSpinner" runat="server" Text="2" Width="120" 
Style="text-align: center"></asp:TextBox>
    <ajaxtoolkit:numericupdownextender id="NumericUpDownExtender1" 
runat="server" targetcontrolid="TextBoxSpinner"
        width="120" maximum="10" minimum="2" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Both the buttons should work for up and down is my expectations.

Comment: Have you checked for any JavaScript error in browser developer console?

Comment: Yes, I have seen there, there is no error showing in chrome browser developer console.